# create a pdf of all bar-line plots appended together

Tags: pdf, plot, sas, pdf-generation, ods

i've created a series of plots using proc gbarline and I wish to export all plots to one pdf instead of just the first plot, I am having two issues:

1. the plot does not export to pdf unless I print the first plot twice, hence why I use the statement

   ```
   %if &index. = 1 %then %do;
   <statements>;
   %end;
   ```
2. the pdf only contains the first plot

The code I use is below:

```
%macro test_pdf;

    data snp (drop=i);
        do i = 1 to 100;
            y = ranuni(0);
            x1 = ranuni(0) * 5;
            x2 = ranuni(0) * 10;
            x3 = ranuni(0) * 7;
            x4 = ranuni(0) * 4;
            x5 = ranuni(0) * 100;
            x6 = ranuni(0) * 50;
            x7 = ranuni(0) * 1000;
            x8 = ranuni(0) * 10000;
            x9 = ranuni(0) * 9999;
            x10 = ranuni(0) * 5984;
            x11 = ranuni(10) * 5;
            x12 = ranuni(10) * 10;
            x13 = ranuni(10) * 7;
            x14 = ranuni(10) * 4;
            x15 = ranuni(10) * 100;
            x16 = ranuni(10) * 50;
            x17 = ranuni(10) * 1000;
            x18 = ranuni(10) * 10000;
            x19 = ranuni(10) * 9999;
            x20 = ranuni(10) * 5984;
            x21 = ranuni(20) * 5;
            x22 = ranuni(20) * 10;
            x23 = ranuni(20) * 7;
            x24 = ranuni(20) * 4;
            x25 = ranuni(20) * 100;
            x26 = ranuni(20) * 50;
            x27 = ranuni(20) * 1000;
            x28 = ranuni(20) * 10000;
            x29 = ranuni(20) * 9999;
            x30 = ranuni(20) * 5984;
            x31 = ranuni(30) * 5;
            x32 = ranuni(30) * 10;
            x33 = ranuni(30) * 7;
            x34 = ranuni(30) * 4;
            x35 = ranuni(30) * 100;
            x36 = ranuni(30) * 50;
            x37 = ranuni(30) * 1000;
            x38 = ranuni(30) * 10000;
            x39 = ranuni(30) * 9999;
            x40 = ranuni(30) * 5984;
            output;
        end;
    run;

    PROC CONTENTS DATA = snp OUT = snp_contents NOPRINT;
    RUN;

    PROC SQL NOPRINT;
        SELECT name INTO: snp_factors 
            separated by " " 
        FROM snp_contents
            WHERE varnum > 1;
        SELECT name INTO: snp_response
            FROM snp_contents
                WHERE varnum = 1;
        SELECT max(length(name)) INTO: max_length
            FROM snp_contents;
    QUIT;

    ODS HTML CLOSE;
    ODS HTML;
    QUIT;

    %LET timestamp = %sysfunc(putn(%sysfunc(date()),yymmddn8.));
    %LET hourstamp = %sysfunc(compress(%sysfunc(TIME(),time.),%str( :)));
    ODS TRACE ON;
    ODS PDF FILE = "&ROOT\output_data\_&timestamp._&hourstamp._Histogram_gbarline.pdf";
    ODS SELECT gbarlin;
    %LET index = 1;

    %DO %UNTIL (%SCAN(&snp_factors.,&index.," ")=);
        %LET factors = %SCAN(&snp_factors.,&index.," ");

        %IF &index. = 1 %THEN
            %DO;

                PROC GBARLINE DATA=snp
                ;
                    BAR  &factors.
                        /
                        FRAME LEVELS=10
                        TYPE=PCT
                        MISSING
                        COUTLINE=BLACK
                    ;
                    PLOT / SUMVAR=&snp_response.
                        TYPE=MEAN
                    ;
                RUN;

                QUIT;

            %END;

        PROC GBARLINE DATA=snp
        ;
            BAR  &factors.
                /
                FRAME LEVELS=10
                TYPE=PCT
                MISSING
                COUTLINE=BLACK
            ;
            PLOT / SUMVAR=&snp_response.
                TYPE=MEAN
            ;
        RUN;

        QUIT;

        ODS PDF CLOSE;
        %LET index = %EVAL(&Index + 1);
    %END;
%mend;

%test_pdf;
```

Comment: Move the `ODS CLOSE` to outside of your macro.

Comment: This is also a portion of your code? Where's the %MACRO statement supposed to be?

Comment: This section is quite self-sufficient, the macro statement is above the data step

Comment: That was clear after @Richard's edit, in your initial post it wasn't in the code block.

Comment: my mistake, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are closing the PDF **inside** the `%DO %UNTIL` loop.

Change

```
    … 
    ODS PDF CLOSE;
    %LET index = %EVAL(&Index + 1);
%END;
```

to

```
    … 
    %LET index = %EVAL(&Index + 1);
%END;
ODS PDF CLOSE;
```

Because you closed inside the loop, only the first iteration was in the PDF output.  The subsequent `ODS PDF CLOSE` statements inside the loop were accepted by SAS and discarded silently (no log messages) because the PDF destination was already closed.